# How to marshal different response types in spray?

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, unmarshalling, spray

Consider an http service that can return two json as response:

successful

```
{
    "yourField":"value"
}
```

failure

```
{
    "errorCode": 3
}
```

To deal with these json's I need to create 2 case classes `case class RespSucc(yourField:String)` and
`case class RespFail(errorCode:Int)`.

For now I have to to something like that:

```
//unmarshal is spray.httpx.ResponseTransformation#unmarshal
if (response.entity.asString.contains("errorCode")) {
    unmarshal[RespSucc].apply(response)
}
else {
    unmarshal[RespFail].apply(response)
}
```

Is there an api to parse these classes automatically without any `if`? E.g. can unmarshaller looks into json fields and select approriate case class?

Answer (score 3):

spray-json supports `Either` which is a very useful data type for this kind of situations.

```
val data = unmarshal[Either[RespFail, RespSucc]].apply(response)

// You can match it
data match {
  case Left(err) => handleError(err)
  case Right(suc) => handleSuccess(suc)
}

// Or you can fold it (I prefer folding)
data.fold(err => handleError(err), suc => handleSuccess(suc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
trait Resp
case class RespSucc(yourField: String) extends Resp
case class RespFail(errorCode: Int) extends Resp

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object ColorJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Resp] {
    def write(r: Resp) = r match {
      case s: RespSucc =>
        JsObject("yourField" -> JsString(s.yourField))
      case f: RespFail =>
        JsObject("errorCode" -> JsNumber(f.errorCode))
    }

    def read(value: JsValue) = value.asJsObject.getFields("yourField", "errorCode") match {
      case Seq(JsString(yourField)) => RespSucc(yourField)
      case Seq(JsNumber(errorCode)) => RespFail(errorCode.intValue())
      case _ => deserializationError("Resp expected")
    }
  }
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

unmarshal[Resp](entitySucc) //Right(RespSucc(abc))

unmarshal[Resp](entityFail) //Right(RespFail(3))
```